# Core Data Unique Constraint Failed after DB Import

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, core-data

I am copying data from an old .sqlite database into a new .sqlite database that I am planning on using from now on in my application. The old database contains a table of `class Thing : NSManagedObject` objects with a number of properties on it.

To copy the data, I am using FMDB to query all of the rows in the old database, and then I do:
`Thing *thing = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Thing" inManagedObjectContext:context]` and then set each property on `thing` using the row from the old database. And end with `[context save:&error]`.

The copying works, and the data shows up in the app. However, when I try to add new data I get an error: `UNIQUE constraint failed: ZTHINGS.Z_PK`. If I just create the new database and do not copy any data over, then new data can be written just fine.

So, there is a problem with me copying old data into the new database that is causing the primary key to be out of whack. Does anyone know what might cause this?

Comment: have you solved your issue ? i am facing same error.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same situation, and solve by followed step:

1 Use DB Browser for SQLite

2 Go to Z_PRIMARYKEY Table Which created by system

3 Change Z_MAX Value to what you need